# Point in Polygon Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, point-in-polygon

I am developing an android application. In the application I have integrated map with polygon. Now I want to check whether the given marker is inside the polygon or not. Help Me please.

Following function is used to check the lat long in the polygon

`pnpoly(no_of_vertex, lat, lng,(float) (point.latitude),(float) (point.longitude))`

```
boolean pnpoly(int nvert, float vertx[], float verty[], float testx, float testy)
    {
      int i, j;
      boolean c = false;
      for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
        if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
         (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
           c =true;
      }
      return c;
    }
```

I got the solution to my question following is the code

```
**private boolean isPointInPolygon(LatLng tap, ArrayList<LatLng> vertices) {
        int intersectCount = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<vertices.size()-1; j++) {
            if( LineIntersect(tap, vertices.get(j), vertices.get(j+1)) ) {
                intersectCount++;
            }
        }
        return (intersectCount%2) == 1; // odd = inside, even = outside;
    }
    private boolean LineIntersect(LatLng tap, LatLng vertA, LatLng vertB) {
        double aY = vertA.latitude;
        double bY = vertB.latitude;
        double aX = vertA.longitude;
        double bX = vertB.longitude;
        double pY = tap.latitude;
        double pX = tap.longitude;
        if ( (aY>pY && bY>pY) || (aY<pY && bY<pY) || (aX<pX && bX<pX) ) {
            return false; }
        double m = (aY-bY) / (aX-bX);               
        double bee = (-aX) * m + aY;                // y = mx + b
        double x = (pY - bee) / m;                 
        return x > pX;
    }**
```

Comment: Please provide more details, as well as what you have tried.   Also, there are many similar questions with answers on StackOverflow. Have you reviewed them for solutions to your problem?

Comment: yes i have checked all the solutions. thanks for the reply i am putting my code as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Point in Polygon aka hit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

Comment: or you can check out this library that does it for you https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Comment: Thanks to all................. But I got the solution and its working perfectly...........

Comment: Thanks man, it saved me.. your code worked perfectly.

Comment: when we are giving the arraylist, we have to provide the starting latlng also as the last latlng?